# Locking shared resources in constructor and destructor

Tags: c++, multithreading

I believe I've got a good handle on at least the basics of multi-threading in C++, but I've never been able to get a clear answer on locking a mutex around shared resources in the constructor or the destructor.  I was under the impression that you should lock in both places, but recently coworkers have disagreed.  Pretend the following class is accessed by multiple threads:

```
class TestClass
{
public:

   TestClass(const float input) :
      mMutex(),
      mValueOne(1),
      mValueTwo("Text")
   {
      //**Does the mutex need to be locked here?
      mValueTwo.Set(input);
      mValueOne = mValueTwo.Get();
   }

   ~TestClass() 
   { 
     //Lock Here?
   }

   int GetValueOne() const
   {
      Lock(mMutex);
      return mValueOne;
   }

   void SetValueOne(const int value)
   {
      Lock(mMutex);
      mValueOne = value;
   }

   CustomType GetValueTwo() const
   {
      Lock(mMutex);
      return mValueOne;
   }

   void SetValueTwo(const CustomType type)
   {
      Lock(mMutex);
      mValueTwo = type;
   }

private:

   Mutex mMutex;
   int mValueOne;
   CustomType mValueTwo;
};
```

Of course everything should be safe through the initialization list, but what about the statements inside the constructor?  In the destructor would it be beneficial to do a non-scoped lock, and never unlock (essentially just call pthread_mutex_destroy)?

Comment: When you say the 'class' is used between multiple threads, I assume you mean an object of type TestClass might be used in multiple threads. In that case, you are still only creating a single object, so you shouldn't need locking in the constructor.  If both threads are in the constructor at the same time, they are making 2 separate objects. It makes more sense to lock around object construction, to make sure (for example) mValueTwo isn't used before the object has finished constructing. Destructor seems like it should lock, to make sure data isn't accessed while being destroyed.

Comment: @Rollie Yes, I did mean the object would be shared.  So, if I create:

Comment: @Rollie: Access to the class while it's destructing is a bug with the instances life-time management - the program is already broken when this happens (if it can be accessed while destructing, it could also happen afterwards).

Comment: @Rollie Sorry, hit enter too soon.        Yes, I did mean the object would be shared.  So, if I create: ` TestClass* testPointer = new TestClass(1.1); ` Then the testPointer is not assigned the address until the constructor fully returns, so no other thread would have access to the object. Is that a correct summary?

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche: Good point, the only concern I would have is - what is the desired behavior if that DOES occur? I'm not 100% sure myself - I would assume the non-scoped lock would perpetually block other threads' access, and perhaps make a subtle error easier to track down. Is there a more elegant way of handling such errors?

Brett, if testPointer is itself shared between multiple threads, you need to guard against both entering that block together at all.  If 2 threads attempt to construct testPointer like this, they will work on 2 separate objects they think are shared.

Comment: @Rollie: I think that really depends on the context. Ideally move the problem upwards by consistently using `shared_ptr` or other resource management helpers to fix the life-time. If that is not an option maybe just `assert()`/crash/... on the locking state.

Comment: An object don't have to protect itself from anything. It is multiple threads that use the object need to protect the object from each other.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Multiple threads cannot construct the same object, nor should any thread be allowed to use the object before it's fully constructed. So, in sane code, construction without locking is safe.

Destruction is a slightly harder case. But again, proper lifetime management of your object can ensure that an object is never destroyed when there's a chance that some thread(s) might still use it.

A shared pointer can help in achieving this eg. :

- construct the object in a certain thread
- pass shared pointers to every thread that needs access to the object (including the thread that constructed it if needed)
- the object will be destroyed when all threads have released the shared pointer

But obviously, other valid approaches exist. The key is to keep proper boundaries between the three main stages of an object's lifetime : construction, usage and destruction. Never allow an overlap between any of these stages.

Comment: Using a shared_ptr is, in general, insufficient. That's because the last thread to drop the shared_ptr will run the destructor, but that thread may not be the last thread to have modified the object. If the object contains complex data members, such as a vector or map, and the destructor doesn't acquire and release a lock, the destructor can see stale memory and cause a crash.

Comment: @MichiHenning : a thread shall only release its shared pointer *after* it completed all operations on the object - which is a very reasonable (if not obvious) requirement. So, locking is unnecessary. Stale memory is indeed theoretically possible, but to deal with that, you need a memory barrier, not locking. (granted, several popular threading libraries include a barrier with certain lock operations, so maybe that's what you meant)

Comment: Here is the scenario. Create shared_ptr<foo> in thread A and pass the shared_ptr (correctly interlocking) to thread B. Thread A updates the state of foo and drops its pointer. Later, thread B drops its shared_ptr, which causes thread B to call the destructor of foo. If thread B hasn't crossed a memory barrier since thread A last updated foo, the destructor of foo will operate on stale data. If foo contains a complex data member, such as a map, that can cause a crash. You are right that a memory barrier is what's needed. It just so happens that a mutex also creates a barrier.

Comment: I have to take this back. The decrement on the shared_ptr is atomic, so it's not possible for the destructor to be invoked without the calling thread having first crossed a barrier. My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

They don't have to be locked in the constructor, as the only way anyone external can get access to that data at that point is if you pass them around from the constructor itself (or do some undefined behaviour, like calling a virtual method).

[Edit: Removed part about destructor, since as a comment rightfully asserts, you have bigger issues if you're trying to access resources from an object which might be dead]

Comment: If another thread might access the object while it's being destroyed, you have a bug and locking won't help (consider what happens if the destroying thread acquires the mutex first). Also, I don't see what wrapping the mutex in a `shared_ptr` will achieve.

Comment: You're right, I agree that you have an issue if there's any chance that you're accessing data from an object that's about to die. The shared_ptr proposal was to avoid a situation where the mutex was destroyed along with the object, but I suppose that you would have to lock that mutex before trying to access anything in that object, so this doesn't work if it's inside the object. I'll edit my answer.